# SwiftUI Overlay within NavigationView z-index layering issues

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, navigationview

I'm pretty new to Swift, so if there is a better way to do what I'm trying to do, please let me know. On the main view, I have a list that navigates to other views, and I have a sidebar that overlays the main view when the user presses the menu button. I want to add navigation links in the sidebar, so I extended the NavigationView to encompass the sidebar view. Now the issue I'm running into is that the Navigation Title and toolbar remain on top of the sidebar when it comes into view.
[Simulator screenshot showing ui components overlaying sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btwDN.jpg)

```
struct ParticipantListScreen: View {
    @ObservedObject var participantListViewModel: ParticipantListViewModel = ParticipantListViewModel()
    @ObservedObject var portalUserViewModel: PortalUserViewModel = PortalUserViewModel()
    
    @AppStorage("lastUpdated")
    var lastUpdated = Date.distantFuture.timeIntervalSince1970
    
    @State var isSidebarOpened = false
    
    @State private var filterParticipantListBy: ApprovalStatus = ApprovalStatus.All
    @State var isLoading = false
    
    var filteredParticipants: [Participant] {
        participantListViewModel.participants.filter{ participant in
            (filterParticipantListBy == ApprovalStatus.All || participant.approved == filterParticipantListBy)
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ZStack{
                VStack{
                    //NavigationView{
                    ZStack{
                        VStack{
                            List{
                                Picker("Show only", selection: $filterParticipantListBy) {
                                    Text("Show All").tag(ApprovalStatus.All)
                                    Text("Approved").tag(ApprovalStatus.Approved)
                                    Text("Denied").tag(ApprovalStatus.Denied)
                                    Text("Pending").tag(ApprovalStatus.Pending)
                                }
                                ForEach(filteredParticipants) { participant in
                                    NavigationLink{
                                        ParticipantDetail(participant:participant)
                                    }label:{
                                        ParticipantRow(participant:participant)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            .navigationTitle("Participants")
                            .toolbar(content: toolbarContent)
                            .refreshable {
                                participantListViewModel.getParticipants(authString: Auth.shared.getAccessToken()!)
                            }
                            //ProgressView().opacity(1)
                        }
                        //}
                        Spacer()
                    }.zIndex(1)
                }
                ZStack{
                    Sidebar(
                        isSidebarVisible: $isSidebarOpened,
                        participantListViewModel: participantListViewModel,
                        portalUserViewModel: portalUserViewModel
                    ).zIndex(110)
                }.zIndex(100)
            }.zIndex(50)
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            participantListViewModel.getParticipants(authString: Auth.shared.getAccessToken()!)
            portalUserViewModel.getUser(authString: Auth.shared.getAccessToken()!)
        })
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

P.S. I'm really enjoying learning SwiftUI, so any other tips on the above code would be awesome. Thanks in advance!

Explain what you did and what you expected:
I tried extending the navigation view to include my sidebar view. I expected to eventually have a sidebar with working navigationLinks. The nav links do work fine, but toolbar components and the navigation title now appear on top of the side bar. I didn't expect it to be perfect right off the bat, but after hours of fiddling and searching, I'm no closer to getting the sidebar to properly overlay all the other ui components.

[Minimum Working Example](https://pastebin.com/N3t4aF77)

Comment: At the first glance, which you should fix first: use `@StateObject` when you _create_ an observed object in the View. Also, please provide a copy&past-able _working_ example. You may provide a mocked version for your observable objects and dummy views.

Comment: Hi Joe! Regarding your code organisation, what did you intent to do with the 
ZStack→VStack→List→Picker ...    Spacer()
Because you don't overlay anything here except a spacer over a VStack ?
ZStack are meant to overlay the elements they contains and only them.
(same for ZStack→Sidebar... ) In the code you provided you should theoretically only have 1 ZStack and 1 VStack

Comment: All of that was me experimenting, and I hadn't cleaned it up yet. I'll get that cleaned and work on getting a working example. Thanks for both of your thoughts!

Comment: Hi both, here is the [working example](https://pastebin.com/N3t4aF77). Is this what you meant?